# Jquery Conflict with Foundation & FlexSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, zurb-foundation, flexslider

I have a jquery conflict on the following page

http://co2oogle.com/other%20sites/chris/index.html

The first reference is on line 16 and is used for the FlexSlider.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The second is on line 213 and is used by Foundation. It's needed for the menu toggle in mobile view.

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
```

I can remove one and the opposite functionality works fine but with both on the page the Flexslider doesn't work.

Comment: y do u have two jquery files?.One should do the job. conflict might be for some other reason..I dont see any conflict in my system-Chrome browser V28.0.1

Answer (score -1):

Did I understand right, you are using Foundation? In that case why don't you use their slider aka Orbit? It is very clean and simple and you would be avoiding conflicts...

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html